# insert photo with wildcard in filename

Tags: excel, vba

1. I have this code:

   ```
   Sub InsertPhotos_Click()
       Range("Photo1").Select
       ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("U:\Trial\1.jpg").Select
       Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 151.2
       Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 27
       Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 3
   End Sub
   ```

I need to be able to name the filename 1-xxxx, but not sure how to use a wildcard.  When the filename is 1, the code does what I want it to.  Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You meant like to rename files? Or additional files that you want to get follow the format 1-xxxx?

Comment: I want the user to be able to name the file 1-(filename), e.g. 1-up close photo.  Then I need the code to recognize the 1- and choose that file, no matter what comes after the "-".  I tried ("U:\Trial\1- & "*".jpg") without success.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
Sub InsertPhotos_Click()
Dim PhotoString As String
    Range("Photo1").Select
    PhotoString = Application.InputBox("Type text for picture", "Get Picture", Type:=2)
    If PhotoString <> "" Then ' 1. If PhotoString <> ""
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("U:\Trial\1-" & PhotoString & ".jpg").Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 151.2
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 27
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 3
    End If ' 1. If PhotoString <> ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but I am going to be inserting 10+ photos, I want them all to be named 1-(filename); 2-(filename); etc.  I just want it to pull the file based on the first two characters of the filename with a wildcard.  Not sure if possible...

Comment: Please explain, first you said you wanted the user being able to name the file and now you want them automatically named? What filename would be? (if picture is named 1; 1-1?)

Comment: I have 8 users naming the files.  I just want them all to name their first photo 1-(something).  Then I want the code to pull the photo that starts with 1-.  They will all be named, however the name will be different each time, depending on what the photo is, except they will all start 1-.

Comment: You would need to loop through files in the folder then, take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow